# Export information from excel into html

Tags: html

I have this code here to log the excel table into the console:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@4.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
            
<script>
  let input = "https://1drv.ms/x/s!Am0AJ8jei5ji0a5ESUueGXWfU1e?e=QaaV";
  input.addEventListener('change', function(){
  readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data){
  console.log(data)
  })
  })
</script>
```

But why doesn't that work? Don't wonder if the link don't work. I changed it.